# Dictionary to Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a dictionary field in my data like so:

```
"details": {
        "code": "PPIO",
        "product": [{
            "productCode": "ADGT"
        }]
    }
```

I need to convert the field to an array of objects:

```
"details":
        [
        {
        "code": "PPIO",
        "product": [{
            "productCode": "ADGT"
        }]
        }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to overwrite existing field:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            details: [ "$details" ]
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xXZ-PP9Nd5l)

EDIT:

For update you can use below [syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/):

```
db.col.updateMany({}, [{ $set: { details: [ "$details" ] } }])
```

EDIT 2:
Alternatively, if `updateMany` doesn't work for you, you can use [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator which will replace your collection entirely with an aggregation outcome:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            details: [ "$details" ]
        }
    },
    { $out: "collection" }
])
```

Comment: how should i go about updating the collection?

Comment: `db.col.updateMany({}, [{ $set: { details: [ "$details" ] } }])`



This doesn't work. Returns the following:



`"details" : [
        "$details"
    ], `

Comment: @balkotdude what is your MongoDB version?

Comment: MongoDB shell version v4.2.3

Comment: @balkotdude this $set is a new feature which was introduced in 4.2 (server version). You can use `$out` (see my modified answer) as a backup